# How to load virtual sub-domain without adding DNS sub-domain in asp.net using URL rewriting?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, dns, subdomain

I have a domain domain.com which hosts asp.net website. I want to add virtual sum-domain blog.domain.com , support.domain.com etc without adding sub-domain under DNS.

I have tried couple URL rewriting option suggested in Stackoverflow itself. but it didn't work.

when hit www.domain.com it taking to me the redirect/rewrite path. but other than www everything loads with default IIS7 page.
Do we really need sub-domain to be created under DNS?

Do we need dedicated IP for this?

Can't we do it programmatically?

Can you anyone please explain in a step by step to implement this?

Comment: Did you add A or CNAME records in the domain.com DNS server? Did you tell your IIS that it should respond to those other aliases?

Comment: yes very much I have added the A records. for TLD it is working. but sub-domain it is not working.

Comment: What about IIS? Something like https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816576

Comment: Showing IIS 7 page with link contains http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=66138&clcid=0x409. i was trying under domain bmge.in and trying to create web.bmge.in and apps.bmge.in

Comment: Your default site is configured to a blank host header? If you have blank host header, the default site accepts any domain not defined in other sites. Every site you make in IIS needs a host header. p.e:

Site 1: host header = bmge.in
Site 2: host header = web.bmge.in
Site 3: host header = apps.bmge.in

Comment: How can I view it? I think, I don't have a control over the headers view or change. Is there any alternate way if I don't have access to it?